# Rails Tutorial: before_filter deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

[Section 10.2.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3arequiring_signed_in_users) of the Rails Tutorial utilizes `before_filter` which is deprecated. What's the modern idiomatic way to write the code in `UsersController` so as to not use `before_filter`?

Here's a version of `edit` that I tried:

```
  def edit
    if ( signed_in? )
      @title = "Edit user"
    else
      deny_access
    end
  end
```

However, this triggers 2 failures in when I run rspec.

```
rspec ./spec/requests/friendly_forwardings_spec.rb:6 # FriendlyForwardings should forward to the requested page after signin
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:266 # UsersController authentication of edit/update pages for non-signed-in users should deny access to 'edit'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`before_filter` isn't deprecated.  You may be confused because the definition was moved to `AbstractController::Callbacks` from `ActionController::Filters::ClassMethods` in Rails 3, but it's still very much alive and kicking.

Here it is defined, deprecation-free, in Rails 3.1:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0.rc6/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L80

Comment: Aha, you're right. Thanks! I'm still curious about the version of `edit` that I posted above. Any idea why that isn't equivalent to using the `before_filter`?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the tests

Comment: Just for completeness, I posted the non `before_filter` version below. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the version of `edit` which doesn't depend on `before_filter` and allows for the specs to pass:

```
  def edit
    if ( current_user )
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if ( current_user?(@user) )
        @title = "Edit user"
      else
        redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    else
      session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
      redirect_to("/signin" , :notice => "Please sign in to access this page.")
    end
  end
```

The original one I posted in the question didn't incorporate `correct_user`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to point to the right solution these days.

`before_filter` is deprecated in Rails 4.2, from the [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes):

> The *_filter family of methods have been removed from the
>   documentation. Their usage is discouraged in favor of the *_action
>   family of methods:

There is a similar question: [Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16519828/462015).

Comment: It's not depreciated now: "These methods will be deprecated in the future and will eventually be removed from Rails."

Comment: Deprecated in 5, will be removed in 5.1 https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/7644a99

Answer (score 1):

[Rails CallBacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb) - `ActionController::Base`, `before_action` is just a new syntax for before_filter.

However, all `before_filters` [are deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193) in Rails 5.0 and will be removed in Rails 5.1

It is just a name change. `before_action` is more specific because it gets executed before an action.