# Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

In rails >4.0.0 generators creates CRUD operations with `before_action` not `before_filter`. It seems to do the same thing. So what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 546, accepted):

As we can [see](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb) in `ActionController::Base`, `before_action` is just a [new syntax](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c) for `before_filter`.

However the `before_filter` syntax [is deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193) in **Rails 5.0** and will be removed in **Rails 5.1**

Comment: On the one hand deprecating has sense but on the other there is a good practice in rails and in ruby to have several aliases for one method so you can use it in different contexts without loss of meaning.

Comment: In 4.2 They are not deprecating it, but removing it from the docs since it is discouraged. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes

Comment: If it's discouraged, then why *wouldn't* you deprecate it?  Silly.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier, it's "discouraged in favor of the `*_action` family of methods", and will be deprecated in the future per @jryancanty's link above. Even Rails has to occasionally bow to not breaking all of the APIs all of the time.

Comment: @JohnWhitley - deprecation doesn't break the API.  That's the whole point of deprecation.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier yes, you can technically ship with deprecation warnings, but the pain level is high since deprecation invariably spams the heck out of your test suite runs.  For any well-disciplined project that keeps clean test runs, this becomes *de facto* breakage.  Therefore, turning on deprecation warnings where there isn't a priority to remove the API in the immediately following release causes an unnecessary fire-drill among the Rails userbase.

Comment: @JohnWhitley - The spamming is for a reason.  Any well-disciplined project should address deprecation warnings by *not using deprecated functions*.

Comment: It's deprecated.  From wikipedia: "Deprecation is an attribute applied to a computer software feature, characteristic, or practice to indicate that it should be avoided".  So essentially they deprecated it but have yet to mark it as such.  Clear communication of these things is overrated.

Comment: It's there: "If your application currently depends on these methods, you should use the replacement `*_action` methods instead. **These methods will be deprecated in the future and will eventually be removed from Rails.**" http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes

Comment: They are officially deprecated in Rails 5 and their use will generate warnings.

Comment: The `<callback>_filter`s are deprecated in Rails 5.0 and will be removed in 5.1: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L190-L193

Answer (score 73):

It is just syntax difference, in rails app there is CRUD, and seven actions basically by name **index**, **new**, **create**, **show**, **update**, **edit**, **destroy**.

Rails 4 make it developer friendly to change syntax **before filter** to **before action**.

**before_action** call method before the actions which we declare, like

```
before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :edit]
```

**set_event** is a method which will call always before show, update, edit and destroy.

Answer (score 33):

It is just a name change. `before_action` is more specific, because it gets executed before an action.

Answer (score 1):

before_filter/before_action: means anything to be executed before any action executes.

Both are same. they are just alias for each other as their behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

use only before_action with rspec-rails, capybara as before_filter will misbehave to give surprises during testing

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
  end
  ## Rest of the code follows
end
```

before_filter

```
feature 'User creates todo' do
  scenario 'successfully' do
    sign_in
    click_on 'Add Todo'
    fill_in 'Title', with: "Buy Milk"
    click_on 'Submit'

    expect(page).to have_css '.todos li', text: "Buy Milk"
  end
end
```

the expected failure is

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for #<TodosController:0x0000558b68573f48>
```

but before_filter gives...

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

That is, somehow the hook runs without error and but the controller goes to view with a @todos uninitialized
Better save time, use non deprecated codes...

Answer (score -4):

To figure out what is the difference between before_action and before_filter, we should understand the difference between action and filter.

An action is a method of a controller to which you can route to.
For example, your user creation page might be routed to UsersController#new - new is the action in this route.

Filters run in respect to controller actions - before, after or around them.
These methods can halt the action processing by redirecting or set up common data to every action in the controller.

> Rails 4 –> _action
>
> Rails 3 –> _filter