# before_action in user controller rendering error: NoMethodError in Users#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails guide (on chapter 9). When I try to access the page corresponding the the user's profile, the browser displays the following error messages:

```
 NoMethodError in Users#show

Showing /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
2: <div class="row">
3:   <aside class="span4">
4:     <section>

Rails.root: /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app
```

Here is my users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])    # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
     sign_in @user
     flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
     redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
         flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
         sign_in @user
         redirect_to @user
      else
           render 'edit'
      end
    end

  def destroy
 User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_url
    end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


  # Before filters

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
 end
end
```

The page loads fine without the line:

```
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

But with it's inclusion things go wrong and I can't figure out why.

Also, here is the routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

 match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: routes file please and what is the url when you access this page.

Comment: that means u r getting nil user in user's profile.

Comment: I just added the routes file in the original post. The url is http://localhost:3000/users/1

Comment: sorry for the question, might sound stupid, but do you have users in db? or when you go to users index page do you have any users listed there? the code looks good to me.

Comment: at what chapter exactly you have this issue?

Comment: Yupp, when I check the development.sqlite3 file I see that there exists users. My issue is in chapter 9 (section 9.2)

Comment: and if you go to localhost:3000/users/  do you have users on your page? p.s. can I look at it in teamviewer?

Comment: do u have any user with specific id u r passing like id = 1. It should not show error if there exists any

Comment: @Debadatt, good point, may be a user with this id doesn't exists

Comment: can you post the html code where your button/link to the show action is? I asume you might not pass id to the controller. Also you can use the current_user like this: @user = current_user

Comment: @Flo, I guess the idea is to have access to any user profile to view them, it's not about only opening your profile.

Comment: What's the last test in the tutorial that you passed successfully and where are you at right now? Also, what specifically are you doing when this error is being invoked?  Are you just going to a specific URL in developer mode?  If so, what is the URL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of **Before Action** in **Users_controller** try before filter 
So your code looks like this:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

I had the exact same error!

Answer (score 19):

If indeed Hurman's answer solved your problem, the reason is because you are running an older version (i.e. <4.0.0) of rails. `before_filter` was renamed in this version to `before_action` (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c), more information in [Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using **4.1.6**.
The problem is that you have defined the before_action as `private`, I don't know why but this type of visibility messes with the controller's before_action load in Rails. So just bring `signed_in_user` outside that area and it should start working again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Hurman Gul's answer, I'll hopefully give you some details about why you're seeing this problem...

---

**Your Controller Is Performing An Action On A Non-Existent Variable**

The error you have is because one of your actions is trying to perform an action on a variable which is either not set, or has no content (is *nil*). The error basically means that you're trying to call the ".name" part of a variable, where it doesn't exist

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
2: <div class="row">
3:   <aside class="span4">
4:     <section>

Rails.root: /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app
```

This basically means that in your view, you're trying to load @user.name, when @user probably doesn't exist. The way I'd recommend fixing this is to initially apply some logic to your view:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<% unless defined?(@user) %>
    Sorry, we could not find your user!
<% else %>

 your code

<% end %>
```