# Undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails and stack overflow. So sorry if there are mistakes in asking this question or...

I'm trying to write edit/update for my blogger project. This is my controller:

```
  def edit
    @post = Post.find params[:id] 
  end   

  def update
    @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :summary, :content))
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

This is my view:

```
<h1>Edit Page</h1>
        <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        Title: <%= f.text_field :title %>
        Summary: <%= f.text_area :summary %>
        Content: <%= f.text_area :content %>
        <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

and when I want to update any post I keep getting this error:

> NoMethodError in PostsController#update
>
> undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Please set @post in before_filter.

Comment: The [new syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519841/2909897) for `before_filter` is now `before_action`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set `@post` instance variable to point appropriate `Post` object in order to perform update on it:

```
@post = Post.find params[:id]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `@post` using a [`before_action`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519841/2909897)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :update]

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Now, whenever rails hits your `edit` or `update` actions it will set `@post` to the "current" post.