# before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index] / Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have a `Listings Controller` (Devise User System) and in **Rails 3** i just used

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
```

to check if a user was signed in before viewing a specific listing.

My Homepage (Index) shows at the bottom a view Listings, the User is able to see them, but as soon as he clicks on one to view it he is redirected to the Login Page.

That's why in my controller i had instead of

```
Listing.new -> current_user.listings.new
```

In **Rails 4** things seems to have changed and i cant find the right way to do it.

I searched a little bit and found that the command was changed to

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
```

A Guest can view now the Index but if he clicks on a Listing, he is not redirected to the login page, instead i get this error.

```
NoMethodError in ListingsController#show
undefined method `listings' for nil:NilClass

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_listing
        @listing = current_user.listings.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

My Listings Controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.order("created_at desc")
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
        @listing = current_user.listings.build
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
        @listing = current_user.listings.build(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
            @listing = current_user.listings.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :image)
    end
end
```

> **EDIT: PROBLEM 2**

If another Logged in User tries to view a listing which another User created im getting this ->

[image]

and the log

[image]

Comment: U might want to do `authenticate_user` before `set_listing`

Comment: You mean just move the authenticate_user above the set_listing line ?

Comment: Just now, and i worked.. Do you mind Posting an Answer so i can upvote it ? :)

Comment: Oh, but now if user wants to view a different user's listing -> NoMethodError in ListingsController#show
undefined method `listings' for nil:NilClass

Comment: ```before_action``` is an alias for ```before_filter```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, this will allow guests to see listing supplied in the parameter:

```
def set_listing
    unless current_user
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    else
        @listing = current_user.listings.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Update:

It appears that you want to display listings by parameter and not by the `current_user`.  If so then please update your `set_listing` definition as follows:

```
def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
end
```

Comment: I got the before action right, with the help of Neo. But now if im logged, in another account, and try to view a listing which is not created from me i'll get  "NoMethodError in ListingsController#show undefined method `listings' for nil:NilClass". With your code also :(

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, can you post the trace from your log.

Comment: Oh, that's because the listing does not belong to the current user.  Why not just find the listing by `id` since you are passing it.  A more proper way would be that once the user is authenticated, your `index` page only shows the listings for the logged in user so that you don't run into errors like this.

Comment: The user now can view other users listings, but can also edit them :(

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, on your `show.html.erb`, you now want to check if the listing belongs to the current user, if it does then show the edit link otherwise do not show the edit link.  for e.g. `<%= link_to_if(@listing.user == current_user, "edit", {controller: "listings", action: "edit"}) %>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34331/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-vinodadhikary)

Comment: Thanks a Lot for taking the time explaining and helping :)

Answer (score 29):

Call `authenticate_user` before `set_listing`, so that `current_user` is not `nil`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

`before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]`

this is used when we want to redirect users to particular page when the user  is not logged in.

in this `",except[:index]"` where the index is pagename of `Html` view where you want to redirect the user.

Answer (score -6):

yes 
You need to call `authenticate_user` before `set_listing`, so that `current_user` is not `nil`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

like this

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?