# Difference between actions and filters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a beginner and I have a really basic question confusing me i.e

- **What is the difference between actions and filters?**

for example we have before_action and after_action in rails 4 but we call them filters, why?
I read somewhere that filters are for controllers and actions are for models, is that it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is different, I mean to ask why we call them FILTERS and what's the difference between filters and actions, and where to use them. obviously actions and filters are not the same thing, and the deprecation seems to be in only a few cases.

Comment: I guess the following commit answers your question. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c It is the same thing. From what I understand, using `*_action`s is misleading but not considered invalid/deprecated.

Comment: And for models there are ActiveRecord callbacks http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: no, I understand the difference between before_action and before_filter but my question is about actions and filters and not *_action and *_filter.
can filters only be used as *_filters ?

Comment: I've never seen filters being used in a different context in Rails. Do you have any examples? Actions are the controllers' methods assigned to the routes.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/ParameterFilter.html  and a few more like filter_by , filter_proxies and filter(backtrace, kind = :silent). there are many more on http://api.rubyonrails.org/  .

Comment: Not sure if the question still stands, you're able to tell them apart now, right?

Comment: no, I have this question. but since I am getting confused between filters and actions, I have no idea how  to implement this. Internet is not much help in this case.
 
'Filters section should contain the following elements & work in the following way
7.1 Quantity - TEXT FIELD where user will enter product quantity (to enter number)

7.2 Price - This will be a select list with following options
BETWEEN 1 to 100
BETWEEN 101 to 500
BETWEEN 501 to 1000

7.3 Discount (in percentage) - This will be a select list with following options
BETWEEN 1 to 10 percent
BETWEEN 11 to 25 percent '

Comment: I guess this is about form filters in HTML. You'd later translate them into DB queries. It has little to do with any filters in rails.

Comment: By sending HTML form to the Rails controller, you'll pass a params hash such as `{quantity: 1}`. Then you should filter your collection of items to contain only those with `quantity == 1`. Given that we have a collection of products `Products.all` we can apply those params to the query by writing `Products.where(quantity: 1)` which will filter out any other products.

Comment: ohh, thanks.. thats was pretty helpful.. just what i wanted!!
suppose i create a view to accept the values then i design a filter in my model 'def self.filter' and i pass in all the parameters through the controller, wil this also work?

Comment: Yep, that's even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this is how I see things:

1: An action is a method of a controller to which you can route to. For example, your user creation page might be routed to `UsersController#new` - new is the action in this route.

2: Filters run in respect to controller actions - before, after or around them. These methods can halt the action processing by redirecting or set up common data to every action in the controller.
For example:

```
before_action :require_logged_out, only: [:new]
def require_logged_out
  redirect_to user_path(current_user) if logged_in?
end
```

So here, `require_logged_out` is a filter which runs before the new action of the users controller.

3: Lastly I'll mention that in Rails 3.x `*_action` filters have been defined via `*_filter`. for example, you'd set a `before_filter` and not a `before_action`.

I think that should wrap things up for you regarding actions and filters in rails.

Comment: Not true anymore. *_filters callbacks got renamed to *_actions https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c
See the Lulu answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actions are the rails 4.0 name for filters. They do the exact same thing but before_action is a clearer name for the behavior.

Here is where the name was changed in code.
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d62e04838f01f5589fa50b0baa480d60c815e2c

Here is a link to another discussion on the matter.
[Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action)