# How to make the whole site accessible by the single admin only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I achieve the following behavior in Ruby on Rails?

I need to make the whole site accessible by the single admin only, so I need to show the authorization page on every not signed in user's action.

What is the best way to do it? Maybe `cancancan` or smth like this? Can you give me an example, please?

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already used Cancan to provide admin abilities, but it's will be a big example. But you can refer to Cancan example from here                           [http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?view=asciicast]

Comment: A simple [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your `ApplicationController` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am big fan of **[ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/)**. You can manage whole site's content and users through Active Admin even it's provide `search`, `filter` & `sorting` facility. as you described that `whole site accessible by the single admin only,` **not signed in user's action**

For your reference:

- **[Live Demo](http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin)**
- **[Active Admin Site](http://activeadmin.info/)**
- **[Documentation](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)**
- **[RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin)**

If you wanted to authorized user for signed in then as papirtiger answered you can simply use that `before_action :authenticate_user!` method

---

### Update:

As you mentioned that all users can access the page then in this case I would like to suggest to use **[cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)** for Rails 4. You can simply assign the roles and as per the roles you can give access to use actions. Provide Role Management System

**OR**

In your Users table append one column of `roles` as boolean type and assign admin user to `false`  and by default all users to `true`. This is the easiest way to achieve your goal.
In your controller set If user's role `false` then he can access everything..

**For E.g.** [Add an Admin Role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Add-an-Admin-Role)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to install it in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991774/unable-to-install-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails-4-1-4. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @FrozenHeart : Answer is posted there

Comment: Ok, now I have a model associated with the database and the admin panel where I can add new records to the DB. But there's still exists 127.0.0.1:3000/purchases page that is accessible for all users. How can I make it accessible from the admin panel only?

Comment: Why does I need to assign admin_user's details in the helper method? I thought that I need to check it. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: No, I don't need to give such permissions for all users, I just need to allow the view / edit / delete permissions to the admin only. But I already have a views like purchases so maybe I need to remove it, create model without any view, migrate DB and add this model to the active_admin? Will it be inaccessible for all other users except admin (because it doesn't even have any view associated with the model)?

Comment: Yes you can in case of just wanted to create model and not allowed use to view / edit / delete and Manage it from backend via admin then ActiveAdmin do that(Remove all View/ Edit / Delete Links)... Cancancan is used for RoleManagement as per the role it give access

Comment: In provided [Live Demo Link](http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin) whatever you see is Backend..

Answer (score 2):

You could use Devise to set it up. Since you want a single user system you don´t need `cancancan` which authorises resources.

Basically you lock down the app by adding a before filter which requires the use to be authenticated:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

There is a guide on how to set up the registration to only accept one user on the Devise wiki. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-devise-as-a-single-user-system

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one user that can access your site then you can use `devise gem` also. Just create simple user using devise. and use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` on your applications_controller.rb . So each request will checked before reaching to controller.

Comment: `before_filter` is gone on rails 3 he tag rails 4

Comment: It's not deprecated in rails 4. before_action is just a new syntax for before_filter. So both can be used. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action