# Unable to install activerecord in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am unable to install `activerecord` in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4.

I've added `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` to the end of `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`. It returns 0, so I've tried to run `rails g active_admin:install` command, but it returns the following error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `install' for
>   main:Object   from (irb):3    from
>   E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in`
>   start'   from
>   E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
>   `start'   from
>   E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in`
>   console'     from
>   E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in
>   `run_command!'    from
>   E:/software/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '    from
>   E:/work/projects/src/technical_support_timer/bin/rails:4:in `require'
>     from E:/work/projects/src/technical_support_timer/bin/rails:4:in`
>   '    from -e:1:in `load'     from -e:1:in`'

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're in console. You want just a terminal session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRB is there for you to try out Ruby commands or snippets and see immediate responses. If you want to install or update gems, I suggest you get off IRB first by running `quit` and follow whatever instructions you have on your hand.