# How to make a public page in an app that uses devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise for Authentication in a Rails 4 app. Almost all of the app requires a user to be authenticated, however, there are a few 'public' pages (Terms and conditions - that kind of stuff).

Devise itself makes the `sign up` and `sign in` pages public, using `prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication`. However, that method [is intended only for devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/901). And devise doesn't seem to provide a 'proper' way to make single actions public.

So, what's the best way to make just a couple of actions public?

The only ways I can think of so far is:

1. To make a new `public` namespace, and have separate controllers for public actions, which inherit from a `PublicController` that does not execute `before_filter :authenticate_user!`
2. Same as above, but ditch the inheritance and the namespace. So the `PublicController` could act as a bucket for anything that needs to be public - which at this stage isn't much.

Is there a better way to make individual actions public with devise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can optionally use skip_before_action for the public controllers. Example from [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters):

```
class LoginsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Comment: @Pedro Please copy/paste the relevant info from the link into your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, you want to have:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
```

This will perform the `:authenticate_user!` method on all actions except `index` action.
You can find more explanation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519841/1290852).

Comment: That'd work if I was doing the : authenticate_user! on a per-controller basis, but at the moment it's in my superclass.

Comment: @joshua.paling I don't know your structure, but when I'm doing pages such as ``Terms of conditions`` or ``About`` I create separate controller for all public pages.

Comment: Yes he is totally right, the ``skip_before_action`` is what you need. Sorry for false response, I didn't know about you having the ``authentication_user!`` in superclass