# Restrict access in Rails app only for users logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and I'm trying to restrict access to pages if a user hasn't logged in and to only allow them to view the login and sign up pages.

Currently, my code creates a session when a user logs in and clears it when the user logs out. I've got a Sessions helper so that I can check whether a user is logged in but I'm unsure how to redirect the user throughout the app if he/she's not logged in.

UPDATE:

1. As I posted the question, I managed to get something to work with a before_filter. Should I use a before_action or before_filter?
2. Do I need to copy the same method in all my controllers where I want to restrict access?

CODE:

/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `before_action`. The rails guide has a nice [section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) with an example on that:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  private

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As I posted the question, I managed to get something to work with a before_filter. Should I use a before_action or before_filter? Also, can I avoid having to copy the same method in all my controllers?

Comment: @Bhav Use before_action, before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1 (refer to this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519841/168377). I believe that if you define `require_login` and `before_action :require_login` in ApplicationController and all your controllers inherit from it, it will be enabled by default, so you don't need to copy anything. You can use `skip_before_action` to turn it off where appropriate.

Comment: @emil.p.stanchev sorry this is super old, but with this method I get the error `redirected you too many times.`