# Pass constant to rails before filter exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got several before filters similar to:
`before_filter :setup_plan, except: :some_action, :another_action, :yet_another_action`

But I have a 3 or 4 exceptions to many before filters. At first I was going to change the logic in all of my before_filter methods, but I found myself repeating a lot of code. In a more perfect world I would have a seperate controller for the actions I want to add, but I've got to add the actions in the same controller, and work around the structure that's already in place.

What I want to do is create a constant or variable with the methods I want to skip in my before filters, such as

```
ACTIONS_TO_SKIP = [:some_action, :another_action, :yet_another_action]
```

And then simply use `before_filter :setup_plan, except: ACTIONS_TO_SKIP`

I get an uninitialized constant error when doing this.  I tried moving this to a method in a helper and also got an undefined method error. 
I know I'm missing something, but can't figure it out.  Is there really no way to pass an method or constant that returns an array of methods I want to skip in my before filters? Just trying to make my controller a little bit cleaner and less verbose.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. "I get an error" is not sufficient information for us to diagnose the problem. What code produces the error? What exactly does the error say?

Comment: where do you define the constant?

Comment: I'm declaring the constant directly after the before filters in the controller, here is the error when trying to access one of the views `uninitialized constant SubscriptionsController::ACTIONS_TO_SKIP`

Comment: ok, then define constant before its used :)

Comment: @apneadiving good call, don't I feel silly

Comment: this is how we all learn you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to declare the constant BEFORE the call to skip. The file is interpreted top down.

```
class FoosController
  ACTIONS_TO_SKIP = [:yes, :this, :and, :something, :more]

  before_filter :setup_plan, except: ACTIONS_TO_SKIP
end
```

Note that in recent Rails versions this is now called `before_action`:
[Rails 4: before_filter vs. before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519828/rails-4-before-filter-vs-before-action)
(perhaps you want to upgrade...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
before_filter :my_before_filter, if: :action_to_skip?

def action_to_skip?
  %w[some_action another_action yet_another_action].member?(action_name)
end
```

Comment: I think this will do, just unless: instead of if: , I want to NOT do the before filter if action_to_skip? is true, I'm gonna give it a go

Comment: Tried this but it execute the before filter anyway

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action
I tried before publishing the answer. It must work. Can you provide part of your code?